# Rspec: test for all controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have rspec controller test:

```
describe TestController do
  it "test all actions" do
    all_controller_actions.each do |a|
      expect{get a}.to_not rais_error(SomeError)
    end
  end
end
```

How to implement `all_controller_actions` method?

Comment: There are more than `get` in actions, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`.

Comment: agree with @Kevin, do not try to DRY your tests. Otherwise you will need to write tests for tests :D

Comment: I have not RESTful contoller with many get actions and this test just an example. @Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I prefer to test one by one, your question is doable.

```
# Must state this variable to be excluded later because MyController has them. 
a = ApplicationController.action_methods

m = MyController.action_methods

# Custom methods to exclude
e = %w{"create", "post"} 

@test_methods = m - a - e

describe TestController do
  it "all GET actions got response" do
    @test_methods.each do |t|
      expect{get t}.to_not rais_error(SomeError)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to write a different test for each action method in the controller.

If you look at the docs on Rails `TestCase` class -- the class that controller tests are created from (even rspec just wraps this class), you'll see what I mean:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html

The docs say:

> > Functional tests allow you to test a single controller action per test method.

The intention is that controller tests have a different test method for each action in the controller.

Comment: I agree with you opinion. But this code just an example, and if you know how to implement `all_controller_actions` method - let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should aim to create a different test for each action of the controller to make tests more expressive and easier to understand. Each action would mostly be located in its own describe blocks, with each meaningful input having its own context block.

For an example:

```
describe "Users" do
  describe "GET user#index" do
    context "when the user is logged in" do
      it "should render users#index"
    end

    context "when the user is logged out" do
      it "should redirect to the login page"
    end
  end
end
```

The example has different authentications for logged in and logged out users, we separated it in different context blocs under the `describe "GET user#index"` block. You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://kolosek.com/rspec-controller-test/).